# HTML form array validation in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

How to validate an array coming from HTML form?

ex:

```
<input type="text" name="test" value="[value1,value2,value3]">
```

In Laravel:

```
$validate = Validator::make(
    $request->all(),
    ['test.*'=> 'max:10']
);
```

But in PHP code the trick doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

In laravel you could try this:

Controller -

```
public function someAction(){

   $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), 

   [
      'test'  => 'required|max:10',
      'test2' => 'required|max:2'
      ]
  );

  if($validator-fails()){

      return Somthing;

    }else{

       // Pass the form input fields values for use
        $test  = Input::get('test');
        $test2 = Input::get('test2');
      }

}
```

Or try this method given [here](http://www.easylaravelbook.com/blog/2015/02/09/creating-a-contact-form-in-laravel-5-using-the-form-request-feature/)